# ScrollSpy Bootstrap angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page HTML and a script angularJS.
I have this menu :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked affix-top" data-spy="affix">
      <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Section2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Section3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section4">Section4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section5">Section5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section6">Section6</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the following sections:

```
<section id="/section1">
</section>
```

... etc.  AngularJS add the "/" after the hash to the url but do the link if I put `"#/section1"` into the href in the menu it doesn't work.

But I have a problem I want to use the scrollSpy of Bootstrap like in this link : http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=scrollspy

But it doesn't work and I think it's because the id of the section isn't the same than the `href` of the menu and angularJS add automatically the "/"

Have you a solution ?

Comment: Take a look how this is implemented > http://oblador.github.io/angular-scroll/

Comment: I have another problem, i have submenu and if the submenu is active the father menu isn't active :/ any solution ?